# slurm 22.05.2 gpu shard is invalid gres name

Tags: gpu, nvidia, sharding, slurm

I'm trying to setup [gpu sharding](https://slurm.schedmd.com/gres.html#Sharding) on a test slurm node (22.05.2 slurmctld + slurmd).
However, regardless of the possible configurations (1. - 3.) I'm using, the sharding does not work at all as `slurmd` ignores sharding as an invalid `gres` name:

```
slurmd: error: Ignoring gres.conf record, invalid name: shard
```

Has anyone got gpu sharding up and running?

Comment: Which GPU and GPU driver version are you using?

Comment: Nvidia A series paired with drivers 515 and cuda 11.7.
For instance, the NVML GPU detection for gres is working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get help in slurm discussion groups.

You did not post the slurm.conf and gres.conf.
I am not sure what might be the issue but here is an issue that may be similar to yours:

https://groups.google.com/g/slurm-users/c/C1CLyPpD1e0

Comment: I don't remember the exact changes, but I did have to remove the line `AutoDetect=nvml` from gres.conf, fill out everything exactly there, and specify everything again in slurm.conf.

So the answer is, just do exhaustive search of all configuration options...

Answer (score -1):

As per the [Official manual](https://slurm.schedmd.com/gres.html#Sharding), in order to use the Sharding i.e, GPU sharing, it must be enabled in the `slurm.conf`. An example would be,

```bash
NodeName=tux[1-16] Gres=gpu:2,shard:200"
```

If this is not present in the `/etc/slurm/slurm.conf` then you are out of luck.

Comment: It is both in `slurm.conf`and `gres.conf` - doesn't work.
If it is in `gres.conf` I get above error and `gres shard` is ignored because "invalid gres name".

If only configured in `slurm.conf`, I get no error, but `shard`isn't configured either, as it doesn't show up in `scontrol show node` as a resource.

Comment: yeah, you are mostly out of luck. Ask the HPC personnel for help.